# Ringtone is starting late as a result of this it gets cut

Tags: ringtone

When we receive a call the ringtone is very slow for the first 3 secs and after that the ringtone plays with full volume. Is that a fault of my phone or everyone is facing the same? The first 3 secs of the ringtone is getting cut as we are hardly able to hear the song.

Comment: This might be a configurable feature. Check your settings and watch out for something like "Ascending ringtone volume". I'm not sure which devices/Android versions/ROMs have that – I just remember there were apps adding this feature, so it's most likely not "omnipresent".

Answer (score 0):

That's how it is on every device. The ringtone starts with a low volume and increases slowly. Set the ringtone volume very high and choose a ringtone with high pitch. I'm not sure if that'll solve your problem but just give it a try.

Comment: Isn't that a configurable feature?

Comment: Root your phone, Install Xposed, Install GravityBox, Disable Ascending Ringtone volume, and Kaboom ! Your phone did not explode.